# creating a new android application from an existing android application

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am a novice in android development but have good experience in iPhone development. I have a source code of an android application and I want to make another android application by copying same code and making changes in images and api. I also want to introduce it in android store with different package name. Can someone please tell me the steps which I need to follow to do it. I feel I will have to create a new project with a new package name but how will I import all of the resources of the existing application?

Regards
Pankaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new project and copying everything, it would be easier to change the package name in existing project (You can make a copy, if you want to preserve the existing project) You would have to mainly change package names after that.

1. You must change the package name in AndroidManifest.xml as that will be used by the market. Also reset the version to 1 and
   versioCode to 1.0
2. Move all the code to a different package. You can do it using Eclipse IDE refactor feature. Right click on the base package in the
   package explorer and choose Refactor | Rename. In the dialog, enter
   new base package name and check "Rename subpackages"

Answer (score 1):

OK Follow these steps:

1). Create New Android Project (Name: MyProject) and define package name (Like pack.test.myproject).

2). Now delete only .java files (not package) in src folder new project.

3). delete the res folder from new project.

4). delete the android.manifest file of new project.

5). Now drag and drop all the .java files on the package name that u want to put in new Project.

6). drag and drop the res folder and manifest file of old project.

7). Now change the images in res drawable folder and add the api by right click on the project -> go to properties -> go to build path and then click on add button.

and run your app.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the source tree, `(...)/myOldApp` -> `(...)/myNewApp`

Working on the copy, you should remove the hidden project settings files (e.g. .project in Eclipse) and just rename the resources, e.g. `(...)/myNewApp/com/pankaj/oldapp` to `(...)/myNewApp/com/pankaj/newapp`

Now rename all occurances of `oldapp` to `newapp` by batch in your favorite editor.

NOW create a new project and choose to use an existing location as your workspace. Point it to your copied location e.g. `(...)/myNewApp`.